# Quickmapservices plugin not showing Google or Bing layers

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, quickmapservices

Ive installed QGIS 3.10.14 on a new windows machine and then the Quickmapservices plugin. However, when I go to the menu, it doesn't show google or bing options. Were they discontinued along the way? Is this a known issue? Is there a solution?

TYVM!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the QMS toolbar, go to `settings` then `more services` then `get contributed pack`

Comment: Ah! But of course! It's been so long since I last installed it that I forgot about that detail!

Many thanks!